# WPF : On screens with different resolution, scroll bar comes even if the window state is maximized

Tags: c#, wpf

my project is using .NET 4.0, I have a WPF application and 2 monitors of resolution 1600 X 900, and 1920 X 1080. In first case I am expecting the scrollbar due to low resolution, when I move my application to HD resolution monitor, and maximize it, scroll bar appears for both X and Y axis.

When both the screens having the same resolution 1920 X 1080, then everything works perfectly, no scroll bar appears.

Snippet for maximize:

```
if (screen != null)
{
    window.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
    window.Left = screen.WorkingArea.Left;
    window.Top = screen.WorkingArea.Top;
    window.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
    window.Height = screen.WorkingArea.Height;
    window.Width = screen.WorkingArea.Width;
}
```

I know in 4.5, I can use SystemCommands to maximize. But I don't know how to resolve this issue in 4.0.
I want to know even if the window state is maximized, why is still the scroll bar is shown?

Comment: Are you asking about scrollbars or window resizing. If you are indeed asking about scrollbars could you please post the code for them?

Comment: asking for window resize to maximum, but scroll bar automatically comes incase of 2 different resolution monitor, In same resolution monitor this is not a problem as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, by checking the properties of window component, somehow the resize mode property reset for different resolution monitor. Maybe it remembers the resize mode of a lower resolution even it's opened on a high resolution monitor.
So below code fixed my problem.

```
if (screen != null)
{
    window.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
    window.Left = screen.WorkingArea.Left;
    window.Top = screen.WorkingArea.Top;
    window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize; 
    window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    window.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
    window.Height = screen.WorkingArea.Height;
    window.Width = screen.WorkingArea.Width;
}
```

I hope it helps others who may be stuck here.

Comment: what is screen in the code ?? can you tell me please?

Comment: @praveen it's System.Windows.Forms.Screen. You can get for example ur primary screen like this  var primaryScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Primary);

Comment: I have tried this but its not working for me .. i have used custom scrollbar through this link https://codeoverload.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/custom-scrollbars-in-wpf/

Comment: i have set the minimum width and height for the window.. After resizing it , the scrollbar will appear.. And i  adjusted the horizontal scrollbar to right side to restore it to maximize screen, when it restored to maximized screen , it is aligned to right side which it was scrollbar positioned..

Comment: Please suggest me on this @MKMohanty

Answer (score 0):

WPF applications are normally independent of your resolution. 
If you want to make the window maximized just use this:

```
 window.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: I know its independent of resolution, but for some strange reason its not working. As you can already see in question I already tried this code. :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an other problem. Otherwise there would be no need to set the WindowState twice. Maybe the time to set these items is not ok.
I had a try in "Window_Loaded" with no success. Now I do the stuff in the window's constructor an everything is fine!

Comment: "Not I do the stuff": did you mean "Now I do the stuff"?